# Spark 2.0+: spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes is not working?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My understanding is that `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is used to control the partition size when spark reads data from hdfs. 
However, I used spark sql to read data for a specific date in hdfs. It contains 768 files. The largest file is 4.7 GB. The smallest file is 17.8 MB.

the hdfs block size is 128MB. 
the value of `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is 128MB.

I expected that spark would split a large file into several partitions and make each partition no larger than 128MB. However, it doesn't work like that.

I know we can use repartition(), but it is an expensive operation.

[image]

Comment: what file format are you using, and which compression?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth a hive table partitioned by utc_date and utc_hour, CLUSTERED BY (idsegment) 
INTO 32 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'='\t', 
  'serialization.format'='\t') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

Comment: Little digging into the source code revealed - "This configuration is effective only when using file-based sources such as Parquet, JSON and ORC."

Comment: how big is your total data?

Comment: @PhanChuong around 100GB